# Schur's lemma proves equivalent irreducible representations are equal?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, equivariant-maps

Let $\phi_1, \phi_2$ be representations of a compact Lie group $G \to V$ that are equivalent. Suppose furthermore that they are irreducible. It follows that there is an isomorphism, $T$, so that: $T \circ \phi_1 = \phi_2 \circ T$.

Schur's lemma states that $T = cI$ for some $c$. Dividing through by $c$ gives $\phi_1 = \phi_2$. This doesn't seem correct. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the form that you are applying it, Schur's lemma only applies to intertwining maps from a representation to *itself*.  Here the two representations have the same underlying vector space $V$ but you need them to actually be the same representation, which just means that $\varphi_1=\varphi_2$.